# Extract sub-project names from multi-module project

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, multi-module

I am trying to extract the subproject names from Gradle Multi Module project and put them in an list (i.e. `["services", "shared"]` ) for below multi-module project

```
> gradle -q projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'multiproject'
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'multiproject'
+--- Project ':services'
\--- Project ':shared'

To see a list of the tasks of a project, run gradle <project-path>:tasks
For example, try running gradle :api:tasks
```

So far I have created a gradle task and I am getting details, but I could not able extract the project name out of `DefaultProject_Decorated`, I tried to look in gradle doc but of not that much help.

```
task('extractSubprojectName') {
    def subProjects = []

    println rootProject.getSubprojects() // [project :'services', project :'shared']
    println rootProject.getSubprojects().getClass() // class java.util.TreeSet

    rootProject.getSubprojects().each { module -> 
        println "Module : " + module // Module : project :'services'
        println "Module Class: " + module.getClass() // Module Class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated

        // I am trying to achieve something like below 
        // subProjects.add(module.getProjectName()) // of course getProjectName() is madeup name which doesn't exits in DefaultProject_Decorated

       // - business requirement on subProjects - 
    }
}
```

Hoping if there is any better solution for it ? or else I have to add logic to convert it to string type and then extract the name out of it.

Comment: Do you want to trigger the REST endpoint using Gradle or using some scripting language and curl?

Comment: I remember we can trigger curl command in Gradle task which will do the job. Anything will do, script or Gradle task whichever is much straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

From its [source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/DefaultProject.java), `getName` might be what you want:

```gradle
tasks.register("zz") {
    doLast {
        println rootProject.getSubprojects()
        println rootProject.getSubprojects().getAt(0).getName()
        println rootProject.getSubprojects().getAt(0).getName().getClass()
    }
}
```

```bash
$ ./gradlew zz

> Task :zz
[project ':aa', project ':bb']
aa
class java.lang.String

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 684ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed to get the "full name", for a `:feature:module` situation. I needed to use `getPath` / `path` to get what I was interested in

```kotlin
rootProject.subprojects {
   println(name) // innermodule
   println(displayName) //project ':outermodule:innermodule'
   println(path) // :outermodule:innermodule
}
```

For your purposes, maybe you need to call something like this?

```kotlin
val subProjectNames = rootProject.subprojects.map { it.path }
subProjectNames.forEach(::println)
```